# xUnit giving unexpected result

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit

I'm currently trying to run a unit test for my web api controller.

Controller:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCaseById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var searchedCase = await _caseService.GetByID(id);
            return Ok(searchedCase);
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("No case found with that ID");
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
        public async Task<Case> GetByID(int id)
    {
        var searchedCase =  await _dataContext.Cases.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        if (searchedCase == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("No user found");

        return searchedCase;

    }
```

Unit Test:

```
public class CaseUnitTest
{

    private readonly Mock<ICasesService> casesService;
    private readonly CaseController caseController;
    public CaseUnitTest()
    {
        casesService = new Mock<ICasesService>();
        caseController = new CaseController(casesService.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetCaseByID_ShouldReturnBadRequest_WrongCaseNumber()
    {

        var result = caseController.GetCaseById(0);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BadRequestObjectResult>(result.Result);
    }
}
```

When I'm calling the method in postman, it returns the BadRequest status. However, When running a unit test, it returns the Ok status. Am I missing something or is there a reason this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your mock to behave correctly. Something along this lines (note that you can make tests async too):

```cs
public class CaseUnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetCaseByID_ShouldReturnBadRequest_WrongCaseNumber()
    {
        var casesService = new Mock<ICasesService>();
        casesService.Setup(service => service.GetCaseById(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ThrowsAsync(new NullReferenceException(""));
        var caseController = new CaseController(casesService.Object);
        var result = await caseController.GetCaseById(0);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
    }
}
```

Some more notes:

- Check out [Moq docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)
- `NullReferenceException` for `GetByID` when case is not found is a quite questionable choice.